# Flex: How to create an Image control from a flash.display.Bitmap?

Tags: apache-flex, image, list, itemrenderer

I need to create an Image control from a Bitmap because I have an ItemRedender to use in a List control.

I'm trying to show a list of images (Bitmaps) in a List control and I couldn't by now.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a bitmap as an image just by creating a new image and setting the source of the image to the bitmap. You can do it like this:

```
var _image:Image = new Image();
_image.source = yourBitmap;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example hopefully this will helps

Please modify image paths

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Embed(source="assets/<image1>")]
            [Bindable]
            public var img1:Class;

            [Embed(source="assets/<image2>")]
            [Bindable]
            public var img2:Class;
            [Bindable]
            private var arr:Array = new Array({image:img1},{image:img2});

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:List dataProvider="{arr}" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:Image source="{data.image}"/>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:List>
</mx:Application>
```